# Javascript new Date(str) - different parsing rules

Tags: javascript

I tried this in the Chrome JS console, with my locale time zone set as PST:

```
(new Date("07-15-2005"))
```

=> Fri Jul 15 2005 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

```
(new Date("07-15-2005")).getTime();
```

=> 1121410800000

but....

```
(new Date("2005-07-15"))
```

=> Thu Jul 14 2005 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

```
(new Date("2005-07-15")).getTime();
```

=> 1121385600000

I was expecting string parsing to occur in both. But I can't make out why when format YYYY-MM-DD is used, it assumes a timezone offset. It's as if I'm expressing "2005-07-15" in my local TZ, but "07-15-2005" is expressed in UTC.

Is the correct explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation seems to be vendor specific, however looking at the documentation of date [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) we see that as of 1.8.5 javascript supports both [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) dates and [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) dates.

As per the [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) documentation ISO 8601 dates are assumed to be in UTC time if not otherwise specified and thus the timezone difference is automatically added.

RFC2822 dates seem to be assumed as local times and as such are not modified.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot seem to replicate your results, but the results seem to differ from browser to browser.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/f7DMV/

In Firefox and Opera, I get only the middle line parsing correctly, the others are Invalid Dates.

In Chrome, both the first and the second line parse correctly (and don't differ), but the last one is still Invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It will vary from browser to browser. The ECMA262 spec says any string which is not in `YYYY-MM-DD` format and is passed to the `Date` function, it may fall back to implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.